# android emulator 2.3.3 - unable to start contacts app by adb

Tags: android, adb, activity-manager

Doing
`adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.start -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact` leads to:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.start typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.start typ=vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact flg=0x10000000 }
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There are intent options. Apps are using intent filters. You can launch the app with intent filters or directly with name.

```
adb shell am start -n  vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact
```

Package name should be vnd.android.cursor.dir and targetted activity should be contact.

-n 
Specify the component name with package name prefix to create an explicit intent, such as "com.example.app/.ExampleActivity".

Please check this link for more details: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#IntentSpec